# FBConnect API is not showing Share page recently in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, fbconnect

i have made use of "FBConnect API" in my app for fb sharing..

Before two-three weeks ago it was working fine. but now it does not display share page at all.

Does any one know what is the issue with it?

OR

Any one know how to resolve this issue?

i have tried other sample apps for FBConnect api but i saw same problem in other app also.

Comment: try this https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

Comment: Can you put code part of your facebook integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get this issues of using old API's. But Below links may help you.
This is a link for new facebook ios sdk

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Tutorial is here to integrate your facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

I have written a code to work for facebook integration with dialog page. You can use my code from below link. but dont forget to include your app id in .plist file and also inside the code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9954128/1083859

Comment: Is there any sample app for new fbconnect api (EXCEPT hackbook)?

Comment: Hey @Bhargavi Trust me.my code works perfectly.i tried lot of times.Just copy that and paste wherever you want.

Comment: I was using old api. I dont want to use graph api. Please tell me if any sample apps are there for new fbconnect api

Comment: I have a sample app.But how could i send that?So try yourself.You can ask whenever you got doubt about that

Comment: no i can't.Its a long process.send me mail to my id.my id is in my profile